# proof of SAT np completeness

Tags: np, computation, np-complete, sat, np-hard

I know if we want to prove the np completeness of some problem we must show these :

- there is a nondeterministic polynomial solution for the problem
- all other np problems are reducible to the problem
  in the case of sat problem it's easy to show "there is a nondeterministic polynomial solution for the SAT problem" but I don't know how to prove "all other np problems are reducible to the SAT problem"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know how to prove "all other np problems are reducible to the SAT problem"

This is known as the Cook Levin Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem .